# What is wrong with this html code?

Tags: image, html

I'm trying to add a clickable LinkedIn button image to our one page html company site.  I was finally able to put a link near bottom of page http://www.tworg.com, but no image appears, just the text "The Willis Organization on LinkedIn". Text should read "LinkedIn Logo" since it's the Alt text, but I changed it so the link made sense.

Here is the code I used:

```html
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/2495544/" rel="nofollow">
  <img src="img/in-black-48px-r.png" alt="LinkedIn Logo" width="48" height="48" />
</a>
```

I am not a programmer, just the person trying to edit this html page which was created for us. Any help would sure be appreciated. I've been at this for days with no luck!

Hopefully,

Linda

Comment: http://www.tworg.com/img/in-black-48px-r.png > Error establishing a database connection

Comment: On the img directory where your web page is hosted you don't have any image called in-black-48px-r.png you only need to load the image, I'm not sure if you be able to put files to your server

Comment: Sorry, David, I'm not sure what you mean or what I should do. Looks as if I've already messed up by posting in the wrong place!

Comment: Genaro, thanks. I thought I had uploaded the image into /img on my host server. Is that what you mean? I just checked and it is in both root and /htdocs. Only difference is upper case letters on server image name, but that doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: Yes Linda, what is the name of the image? I can check for you if works, on the server I mean

Comment: I must go Linda, I posted an answer hope helps. Regards.

Comment: Hi Linda, I would really appreciate you to tell me why you downvoted me. I am certain that my answer is correct, by if you tell me what was wrong about it, that will help me improve my answers in the future.

Comment: @Linda The image name must be exactly the same in the html as on the disk. Names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain a little bit, your html code is not wrong, the problem is that your server doesn't find the image, as you declare on `src="img/in-black-48px-r.png"` you are telling to your server to look to the img directory to see if there is the image called `in-black-48px-r.png`.

At this point you have two options, use a src that points to a image on the web (not the best) or load the image to your server into the img directory with the same name you used on your img tag.

[image]

Here you can see that at this time you don't have that image on that directory and your server only find the other two.

As other answer suggest you can easily check if your server has the desired image, only put `http://www.tworg.com/img/in-black-48px-r.png`, if the image is correctly load and named in your server you be able to see it on the browser with that url. You should notice that is case sensitive the name of the image.

Answer (score 0):

your image src is incorrect, if you put correct src, this code will work

[image: not loaded image]

```html
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/2495544/" rel="nofollow">
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/000d46f3f287035549b18cc7fa215dbc" alt="LinkedIn Logo" width="48" height="48" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things wrong with your code:

1. The image url looks wrong:  points to http://www.tworg.com/img/in-black-48px-r.png which gives me an error message
2. Width and height cannot be set that way.  should be:  `<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/2495544/" rel="nofollow"><img src="[FIX THIS]" alt="The Willis Organization on LinkedIn"  style="width:48px;height48px;"></a>`

Comment: I see, Ronald. I tried your link and got the error message, too. I can fix the way I've done the image size (thanks), but am stumped about the image source. I got the url for the image by sort of copying what the original developer had done for the image of our logo at the top of the site page: <img title="The Willis Organization" src="img/logo.png".I uploaded my LinkedIn icon into the same folder as the logo. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

On your root folder/main directory, name a folder "images", exactly as quoted. Download the LinkedIn Brand Asset Logo and placed it in the "images" folder. Let's say the image itself is called, "LinkedInLogo.jpg".
Then, place the following code:

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company-beta/2495544/" height="48" width="48">
<img src="images/LinkedInLogo.jpg" alt="LinkedIn Logo">
</a>
```

This should work, however, I noticed it's not dissimilar to your own code - so be sure to spell everything exactly as is. Including upper and lower case. If a folder is within a folder, you must denote it with a "/" so for instance, say my images are in a folder called bananas, I would have to write "bananas/[ImageIWantToReference.jpg]"

Comment: Thanks for your specific instructions. Being new to this, my head is buzzing so I'm going to shut down, get some sleep and try your solution in the morning. Thank you SO much for your help, cmprogram. This sounds as if it will work...create a whole new folder and type carefully. Will post back results in morning.

Answer (score 0):

Well, good grief! I just tried editing the image file name, changing the upper case letters to lower case. I then uploaded that image to server, deleted upper case one...and it worked!

The chosen LinkedIn icon shows up on the page!

Thank all of you for your help. You were right: the image was not being picked up by the server. I'm delighted with this forum now that I've actually used it myself. So impressed by how many helpful - and patient! - programmers came to my rescue.

Linda